# How to use absolute links in Symfony without breaking app_dev.php?

Tags: symfony

This is the problem:

I have a menu link which I want to resolve to domain/course/2

This menu link is on a menu bar. The menu bar is visible on all pages of the web site including /home and /course/1

If I code the menu link like this:

```
href="/course/2"
```

then that works fine for navigation. However if I am on /domain/app_dev.php/course/1 then that style of doing the links loses the app_dev and I jump into production i.e. I go to domain/course/2 not /domain/app_dev.php/course/2. Not what I want.

However if I code the menu link like this:

```
href="course/2"
```

Then that does not break app_dev. However the navigation breaks. Because it is a relative path if I am in /course/1 when I click on that link I end up in /course/course/2 which of course (no pun intended) doesn't exist.

I can see how I can fix this by making my nav bar know what page (directory) it is being loaded on and set the links dynamically. But this feels a bit "hacky".

This must be a v. common problem with Symfony. How is it best solved?

Comment: I don't see a problem using symfony's URL generator at all. Are you saying you hard code the urls or something? Can you provide an example of how you create your links?

Comment: Thanks Artamiel. Typical Symfony. It is easy when you know how. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are generating links in "hardcode" style, instead of

```
href="/course/2"
```

you should use "path" function, so if you have the route name "closure" for your controller action, then you should use

```
href="{{ path('closure', {id: 2})}}"
```

Where "id" is expected action parameter. And I suppose you use Twig as template engine

Comment: Yes. I was. Am now using path(). And yes twig.